# KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "skintype_64_rmsprop_{val_loss:.3f}.h5". Reason: \'val_loss\''

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have been trying to train my skin type classification model but it shows error.

```
model_name = f"skintype_{batch_size}_{optimizer}"
tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join("logs", model_name))
# saves model checkpoint whenever we reach better weights
modelcheckpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_name + "_{val_loss:.3f}.h5", save_best_only=True, verbose=1)

history = m.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, 
                steps_per_epoch=n_training_samples // batch_size, 
                validation_steps=n_validation_samples // batch_size, verbose=1, epochs=30,
                callbacks=[tensorboard, modelcheckpoint])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Keras, and I only took a brief look at your code, but I think I see what's wrong.  In the line:

```
modelcheckpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_name + "_{val_loss:.3f}.h5", save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
```

Keras is complaining about `val_loss`.  I bet you want the format string containing that reference (`"_{val_loss:.3f}.h5"`) to have a `f` at the front of it so that the reference gets interpreted and replaced with a value before it is passed into `ModelCheckpoint`.  I think you need just a one character addition to get over this hurdle:

```
modelcheckpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_name + f"_{val_loss:.3f}.h5", save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
```

I hope I'm right and that this knowledge gets you cruising along again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried it still showed the same error :(

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  I mean, it can still be broken, but adding that `f` should change the behavior at least a little bit.  You did mean for that string to get computed before you passed it into `ModelCheckpoint`, right?  If you're running a Python that doesn't know about `f`, then you should get an error saying that.  If `val_loss` isn't defined, you'd get an error about that.  Otherwise, that string should change so something like `_3.00.h5`.  I don't get how it can be exactly the same error. Is it just a similar error maybe?

Comment: I fixed it Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with the metrics you have mentioned in model.compile() as well.

For example, my ModelCheckpoint looks like this

```
path = "ops/model-{epoch:02d}-{val_categorical_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = path ,monitor ='val_categorical_accuracy',save_best_only=True,save_weights_only=True,mode='max',shuffle=True,verbose = 1,save_freq='epoch')
```

and my model.compile() looks like this:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
```

Most likely the reason why keras has an issue with val_loss is that you havent mentioned the metrics properly while compiling.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the problem is when the `batch_size` is larger than the validation dataset, `model.fit()` fails to load any validation data (`val_loss`, `val_acc` etc.), which results in no validation-related metrics in the `log` variable (see *filepath* under *Arguments*) within the `ModelCheckpoint.on_epoch_end` function.

Try to reduce the `batch_size` or increase the validation dataset, which is fed into `model.fit()`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the available storage on your Google Drive? If there is not enough storage, it cannot be saved.